# format of a script which installs programs as root, but configures for a regular user?

Tags: bash

I am writing some bash scripts to install *and configure* some programs.
Because the script needs to install packages - I run the scripts as root - which itself is no problem (i.e. I have root privileges etc).
However once the packages are installed I want to then configure the normal user files,ideally I would do this as a regular user, as any config files created would be owned by root

An example program snippet is something like

```
#! /bin/bash

# Because this statement needs to be run as root - the entire script is 
# also run as root
apt-get install -y tmux

cat << EOF > ~/.tmux.conf
# 
# config stuff
#
EOF
```

Do I need to manually revert file privileges to regular user, at the end of the script - which is simple for a single file, but could get tricky in some situations.
e.g. add something like

```
chown $USER:$USER ~/.tmux.conf 
chmod 755 ~/.tmux.conf
```

Or is there a better way to handle this - like execute the `~/.tmux.conf` statement in a subshell as a regular user?

Comment: You could write the config to a temporary file and then move it in place with  the `install` command.

Comment: thanks, can you elaborate a bit more? does the install command apply regular user permissions to config files?

Answer (score 0):

I got a working solution thanks to @jordanm pointing me in the right direction.

- Docs available at `info coreutil 'install invocation'`

Basically the GNU `install` command provides alot of options about managing the files as you move them to their final destination.

simply created a temporary file `temp.txt`, then ran

```
install temp.txt final/final.txt --owner=regular_user --mode=755
```